# Is there a constructive proof that $2^X$ can't inject into $X$?

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics

Let $X$ be a set.  Constructively, it is not hard to show that $\mathcal{P}(X)$ does not inject into $X$:  If $f : \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow X$ is an injection, consider $D := \lbrace x \in X \mid  \exists Y f(Y) = x \wedge x \not\in Y \rbrace$.  Then $f(D) \in D \Leftrightarrow f(D) \not\in D$.

However, this argument doesn't carry over if we replace $\mathcal{P}(X)$ with $2^X$, since the $D$ from above cannot generally be assumed to be decidable.  Is there another argument that works for $2^X$ or is the statement that $2^X$ doesn't inject into $X$ independent of constructive mathematics?

Edit:  $2^X$ is the set of functions from $X$ to $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$, or equivalently, the decidable subsets of $X$.  In constructive mathematics we are not able to conflate $\mathcal{P}(X)$ and $2^X$.

Comment: What does $2^X$ mean if not $\mathcal{P}(X)$?

Comment: perhaps you're asking something more subtle than I'm seeing, but what's wrong with using the standard bijection between $2^X$ and $\mathcal{P}(X)$?

Comment: @GFauxPas I assume $2^X$ is the set of all functions $X \to \{0,1\}$.

Comment: @DanRust correct, but $2^X$ and $\mathcal{P}(X)$ can't be assumed equivalent without the law of excluded middle.

Comment: @user181407 that would be the subtlety I was missing, haha

Comment: Isn't there at most a countable number of decidable subsets?

Comment: @user181407 Can you say a bit about *why* we can't conflate them? That comes as a surprise to me (although I'm not at all well-versed in constructive mathematics).

Comment: @NoahSchweber in constructive settings, one can still construct a non-computable set $S = \lbrace n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \phi(n) \rbrace$ for non-computable predicate $\phi$, but generally one cannot then construct from that a corresponding characteristic function $\chi_S : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow 2$.

Comment: @user181407 Right, IZF has separation; I forgot about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's consistent with constructive mathematics that there is an injection from $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, and in particular composing with the inclusion $2^\mathbb{N} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ gives an injection $2^\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.

This was proved not so long ago by Andrej Bauer in [An injection from the Baire space to natural numbers](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0960129513000406). The proof is basically to work in a realizability model over infinite time Turing machines. Similarly to the more usual forms of realizability, in the model the functions $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ are those that are computable by some infinite time Turing machine, $\psi_e$. However, with infinite time Turing machines we can compute a partial function $r : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that if $\psi_e$ is total, then $r(e)$ is defined and $\psi_{r(e)} = \psi_e$, and so that if $\psi_e = \psi_{e'}$ (ie $e$ and $e'$ are programs that happen to give the same function), then $r(e) = r(e')$. In the realizability model, this means that we get an actual well defined function $R\colon \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that for any $f \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$, $f = \psi_{R(f)}$. Any such function is necessarily injective.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks!